# Android run the code on release apk Signed By Google

Tags: android, android-studio, apk, android-install-apk

I have app which is published already in Google Play store and the "App Signing by Google Play" is enabled...
[image: App Singing Docs]

Which mean if someone download the app from store he will have different signature from what I have when creating Signed-apk from my android studio.

I have some device which have the APK signed by google and I want to run a new version over it from my android studio.. How can create apk with same Signature that App Google Signing use.

[image: Downloadable certificate]

Can I create jks file from the .der file ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you can't create a keystore from a .der file: the der file only contains the pubic key whereas you need the private key to sign an APK.

If you opted for Google to generate the app signing key, you won't be able to sign the APK yourself with that key since Google doesn't allow you to download the private key (for security reasons). So you will have to upload an APK to a closed track then download the generated APK either from the Play Store (if you're enrolled in that track) or from the Artifact Library in the Console.

I would recommend to test locally with a different key so you can test the upgrade easily offline, then when you're ready to release, test on a closed track with the app signing key.

Comment: I want to run over released version because I want some important data in the client (Bug happened)... Of course when I test I don't use the signing key.

Comment: I will use Closed track then download the apk. Thank You

Comment: @Pierre
"you will have to upload an APK to a closed track then download the generated APK either from the Play Store (if you're enrolled in that track) or from the Artifact Library in the Console." 

Then APK will be unsigned in the above case?
If yes then How we generate a signed APK available for users?

Comment: The APK you download from the Play Store or the Play Console would be signed.